# Get ADcomputer Buil windows extend

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I wanted to know if I can retrieve via script or powershel command the extended build of windows in order to make a report of the computers which received the last patch and those which are in later version

What i want

[image: What I want]

for the moment I found this command but I only get the windows build
It only allows me to know which version of windows 10 the computers have

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystemVersion | Select-Object -Prperty Name, OperatingSystemVersion
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you will find this information stored in the AD Computer Objects, you would likely need to use something like `Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object BuildNumber, Version`

Comment: These information is not stored in AD. You will have to query each individual PC for it.

Comment: how i can have this information ?
we do not use SCCM but IVANTI

Comment: @LB_34 Above you are told how to do it on a computer. If you need to query computers you will need to use a ```foreach``` and then ```invoke-command```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystemVersion, operatingSystem, name | #
Where-Object {($_.operatingSystem -like "Windows*")} | 
Select-Object name, OperatingSystemVersion | sort name #or OperatingSystemVersion
```

If you want a build version:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name "UBR").UBR
```

By

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName name -ScriptBlock {}
```